# Detect mouse scroll actions jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, scroll, jquery-animate

I am developing a image gallery and was successful up to doing the scrolling. Images slide left and right when the mouse scrolls up and right respectively. I used animate({"top","left"},500) to animate images as sliding. But my problem is that when the mouse scrolls two or more times at once it takes 1000ms to complete because on each scrolling animation is called.

Is there any way to speed up the image animation with respect to mouse scroll speed?

I can't give you any code because I don't whether this can be done. ANY SUGGESTION ON HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS?

**EDIT**

posn is an array with top and left, `var posn = [{x:"50%",y:"50%"},{x:"40%",y:"70%"},{x:"30%",y:"90%"},{x:"30%",y:"10%"},{x:"40%",y:"30%"}];`

```
$("#photo0").animate({"top":""+posn[0].x,"left":""+posn[0].y},500);
$("#photo1").animate({"top":""+posn[1].x,"left":""+posn[1].y},500);
```

There are 5 photos with #photo2,#photo3,#photo4

Comment: What's the current code `animate({"top","left"},500)` in full?

Comment: Could you use `.stop().animate()` to stop the current animation and move onto the next one? I don't really know how your code works so you may want to include it in your question.

Comment: I'd be interested to see anyone post an answer for this. I don't think it's possible. Isn't your problem that you are firing multiple animations when you should only fire a single animation? Just curious if you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @MikeC. of course it's possible - the answer is exactly what you said.

Comment: So then, how does he speed up the image animation speed based on mouse scroll?

Comment: @MikeC. is there any way to detect the scroll speed...

Comment: That is what I'm saying I do not believe is possible to detect. I mean, you can time the distance(in time) between scroll events...but I think Matt's answer my be what you really need, not trying to figure out how to base your animation on the scroll speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [debounce the scroll callback](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) so that it isn't fired as frequently while scrolling. If you make sure it only fires every 500 ms (the same duration as your animation) the two should line up nicely.